# 404 Page not / No webpage was found for the web address Found in Angular Routing for Mobile View

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router, url-routing, angular2-routing

I had developed an angular app. when I use **ng build --prod** to build for production and hosting I found that on mobile view except for home page, in all routings *it shows 404 Page not Found.* I am not able to figure out why it is so.

**CODE OF APP-ROUTING-MODULE.TS**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, PreloadAllModules, Router } from '@angular/router';
//import { GalleryPageComponent } from './components/pages/gallery-page/gallery-page.component';
//import { EventsPageComponent } from './components/pages/events-page/events-page.component';
import { ErrorPageComponent } from './components/pages/error-page/error-page.component';
import { CaseStudiesThreeColumnsPageComponent } from './components/pages/case-studies-three-columns-page/case-studies-three-columns-page.component';
//import { HomepageOneComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-one/homepage-one.component';
//import { HomepageTwoComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-two/homepage-two.component';
//import { HomepageThreeComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-three/homepage-three.component';
import { HomepageFourComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-four/homepage-four.component';
import { AboutPageComponent } from './components/pages/about-page/about-page.component';
//import { TeamPageComponent } from './components/pages/team-page/team-page.component';
import { ServicesPageComponent } from './components/pages/services-page/services-page.component';
import { ServicesDetailsPageComponent } from './components/pages/services-details-page/services-details-page.component';
import { ContactPageComponent } from './components/pages/contact-page/contact-page.component';
import { BlogPageComponent } from './components/pages/blog-page/blog-page.component';
//import { BlogDetailsPageComponent } from './components/pages/blog-details-page/blog-details-page.component';
import { CaseStudiesDetailsPageComponent } from './components/pages/case-studies-details-page/case-studies-details-page.component';
//import { FaqPageComponent } from './components/pages/faq-page/faq-page.component';
//import { EventsDetailsPageComponent } from './components/pages/events-details-page/events-details-page.component';
import { CoursesPageComponent } from './components/pages/courses-page/courses-page.component';
import { CoursesDetailsPageComponent } from './components/pages/courses-details-page/courses-details-page.component';
import { ApplicationStateService } from './application-state.service';

const mobile_routes:Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'home', component: HomepageFourComponent},
    {path: 'about-us', component: AboutPageComponent},
    {path: 'services', component: ServicesPageComponent},
    {path: 'services/:id', component: ServicesDetailsPageComponent},
    //{path: 'gallery', component: GalleryPageComponent},
    {path: 'courses', component: CoursesPageComponent},
    {path: 'courses/:id', component: CoursesDetailsPageComponent},
    //{path: 'events', component: EventsPageComponent},
    //{path: 'events-details', component: EventsDetailsPageComponent},
    {path: 'case-studies', component: CaseStudiesThreeColumnsPageComponent},
    {path: 'case-studies/:id', component: CaseStudiesDetailsPageComponent},
    {path: 'error', component: ErrorPageComponent},
    //{path: 'faq', component: FaqPageComponent},
    {path: 'blog', component: BlogPageComponent},
    //{path: 'blog-details', component: BlogDetailsPageComponent},
    {path: 'contact', component: ContactPageComponent},
    {path: '**', component: ErrorPageComponent}
]
const Dekstop_routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'home', component: HomepageFourComponent},
    {path: 'about-us', component: AboutPageComponent},
    {path: 'services', component: ServicesPageComponent},
    {path: 'services/:id', component: ServicesDetailsPageComponent},
    //{path: 'gallery', component: GalleryPageComponent},
    {path: 'courses', component: CoursesPageComponent},
    {path: 'courses/:id', component: CoursesDetailsPageComponent},
    //{path: 'events', component: EventsPageComponent},
    //{path: 'events-details', component: EventsDetailsPageComponent},
    {path: 'case-studies', component: CaseStudiesThreeColumnsPageComponent},
    {path: 'case-studies/:id', component: CaseStudiesDetailsPageComponent},
    {path: 'error', component: ErrorPageComponent},
    //{path: 'faq', component: FaqPageComponent},
    {path: 'blog', component: BlogPageComponent},
    //{path: 'blog-details', component: BlogDetailsPageComponent},
    {path: 'contact', component: ContactPageComponent},
    {path: '**', component: ErrorPageComponent}
];
//{useHash: true}
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(Dekstop_routes,{preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules})],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
    public constructor(private router: Router,
        private applicationStateService: ApplicationStateService) {

        if (applicationStateService.getIsMobileResolution()) {
          router.resetConfig(mobile_routes);
        }
      }
}
```

**CODE OF APP.MODULE.TS:-**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

```
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { GalleryPageComponent } from './components/pages/gallery-page/gallery-page.component';
import { EventsPageComponent } from './components/pages/events-page/events-page.component';
import { ErrorPageComponent } from './components/pages/error-page/error-page.component';
import { CaseStudiesThreeColumnsPageComponent } from './components/pages/case-studies-three-columns-page/case-studies-three-columns-page.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/layouts/footer/footer.component';
import { PreloaderComponent } from './components/layouts/preloader/preloader.component';
import { HomepageOneComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-one/homepage-one.component';
import { SolutionsComponent } from './components/common/solutions/solutions.component';
import { HomeoneServicesComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-one/homeone-services/homeone-services.component';
import { HomeoneProcessComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-one/homeone-process/homeone-process.component';
import { HomeoneCaseStudiesComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-one/homeone-case-studies/homeone-case-studies.component';
import { HomeoneScientistComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-one/homeone-scientist/homeone-scientist.component';
import { HomeoneTestimonialsComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-one/homeone-testimonials/homeone-testimonials.component';
import { HomeonePartnerComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-one/homeone-partner/homeone-partner.component';
import { HomeoneBlogComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-one/homeone-blog/homeone-blog.component';
import { ProjectStartComponent } from './components/common/project-start/project-start.component';
import { HomeoneAboutComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-one/homeone-about/homeone-about.component';
import { HomeoneBannerComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-one/homeone-banner/homeone-banner.component';
import { HomepageTwoComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-two/homepage-two.component';
import { HometwoPartnerComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-two/hometwo-partner/hometwo-partner.component';
import { HometwoTestimonialsComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-two/hometwo-testimonials/hometwo-testimonials.component';
import { HometwoScientistComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-two/hometwo-scientist/hometwo-scientist.component';
import { HometwoProcessComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-two/hometwo-process/hometwo-process.component';
import { HometwoServicesComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-two/hometwo-services/hometwo-services.component';
import { HometwoFunfactsComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-two/hometwo-funfacts/hometwo-funfacts.component';
import { HometwoMissionComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-two/hometwo-mission/hometwo-mission.component';
import { HometwoAboutComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-two/hometwo-about/hometwo-about.component';
import { HometwoBannerComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-two/hometwo-banner/hometwo-banner.component';
import { HometwoBoxesComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-two/hometwo-boxes/hometwo-boxes.component';
import { HomethreeBannerComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-three/homethree-banner/homethree-banner.component';
import { HomepageThreeComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-three/homepage-three.component';
import { HomethreePartnerComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-three/homethree-partner/homethree-partner.component';
import { HomethreeFeaturedServicesComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-three/homethree-featured-services/homethree-featured-services.component';
import { HomethreeAboutComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-three/homethree-about/homethree-about.component';
import { HomethreeMissionComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-three/homethree-mission/homethree-mission.component';
import { HomethreeFunfactsComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-three/homethree-funfacts/homethree-funfacts.component';
import { HomethreeCoursesComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-three/homethree-courses/homethree-courses.component';
import { HomethreeExploreLearningComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-three/homethree-explore-learning/homethree-explore-learning.component';
import { HomethreeBootcampsComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-three/homethree-bootcamps/homethree-bootcamps.component';
import { HomethreeTestimonialsComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-three/homethree-testimonials/homethree-testimonials.component';
import { HomethreeBlogComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-three/homethree-blog/homethree-blog.component';
import { SubscribeComponent } from './components/common/subscribe/subscribe.component';
import { HomepageFourComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-four/homepage-four.component';
import { HomefourBlogComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-four/homefour-blog/homefour-blog.component';
import { HomefourTestimonialsComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-four/homefour-testimonials/homefour-testimonials.component';
import { HomefourIndustriesServeComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-four/homefour-industries-serve/homefour-industries-serve.component';
import { HomefourServicesComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-four/homefour-services/homefour-services.component';
import { HomefourFunfactsComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-four/homefour-funfacts/homefour-funfacts.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/layouts/navbar/navbar.component';
import { HomefourWhatWeDoComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-four/homefour-what-we-do/homefour-what-we-do.component';
import { HomefourWhyChooseUsComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-four/homefour-why-choose-us/homefour-why-choose-us.component';
import { HomefourFeaturedServicesComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-four/homefour-featured-services/homefour-featured-services.component';
import { HomefourBannerComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-four/homefour-banner/homefour-banner.component';
import { AboutPageComponent } from './components/pages/about-page/about-page.component';
import { AboutpageAboutComponent } from './components/pages/about-page/aboutpage-about/aboutpage-about.component';
import { AboutpageHistoryComponent } from './components/pages/about-page/aboutpage-history/aboutpage-history.component';
import { TeamPageComponent } from './components/pages/team-page/team-page.component';
import { ServicesPageComponent } from './components/pages/services-page/services-page.component';
import { ServicesDetailsPageComponent } from './components/pages/services-details-page/services-details-page.component';
import { ContactPageComponent } from './components/pages/contact-page/contact-page.component';
import { BlogPageComponent } from './components/pages/blog-page/blog-page.component';
import { BlogDetailsPageComponent } from './components/pages/blog-details-page/blog-details-page.component';
import { RelatedServicesComponent } from './components/pages/services-details-page/related-services/related-services.component';
import { CaseStudiesDetailsPageComponent } from './components/pages/case-studies-details-page/case-studies-details-page.component';
import { RelatedCaseStudiesComponent } from './components/pages/case-studies-details-page/related-case-studies/related-case-studies.component';
import { FaqPageComponent } from './components/pages/faq-page/faq-page.component';
import { EventsDetailsPageComponent } from './components/pages/events-details-page/events-details-page.component';
import { EventsSpeakersComponent } from './components/pages/events-details-page/events-speakers/events-speakers.component';
import { CoursesPageComponent } from './components/pages/courses-page/courses-page.component';
import { CoursesDetailsPageComponent } from './components/pages/courses-details-page/courses-details-page.component';
import { RelatedCoursesComponent } from './components/pages/courses-details-page/related-courses/related-courses.component';
import { MLComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-four/homefour-services/ml/ml.component';
import { BigDataComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-four/homefour-services/big-data/big-data.component';
import { IOTComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-four/homefour-services/iot/iot.component';
import { WebComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-four/homefour-services/web/web.component';
import { AppsComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-four/homefour-services/apps/apps.component';
import { DataScienceComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-four/homefour-services/data-science/data-science.component';
import { CloudComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-four/homefour-services/cloud/cloud.component';
import { TrainingComponent } from './components/pages/homepage-four/homefour-services/training/training.component';
import { ComingSoonPageComponent } from './components/pages/coming-soon-page/coming-soon-page.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    GalleryPageComponent,
    EventsPageComponent,
    ErrorPageComponent,
    CaseStudiesThreeColumnsPageComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    PreloaderComponent,
    HomepageOneComponent,
    SolutionsComponent,
    HomeoneServicesComponent,
    HomeoneProcessComponent,
    HomeoneCaseStudiesComponent,
    HomeoneScientistComponent,
    HomeoneTestimonialsComponent,
    HomeonePartnerComponent,
    HomeoneBlogComponent,
    ProjectStartComponent,
    HomeoneAboutComponent,
    HomeoneBannerComponent,
    HomepageTwoComponent,
    HometwoPartnerComponent,
    HometwoTestimonialsComponent,
    HometwoScientistComponent,
    HometwoProcessComponent,
    HometwoServicesComponent,
    HometwoFunfactsComponent,
    HometwoMissionComponent,
    HometwoAboutComponent,
    HometwoBannerComponent,
    HometwoBoxesComponent,
    HomethreeBannerComponent,
    HomepageThreeComponent,
    HomethreePartnerComponent,
    HomethreeFeaturedServicesComponent,
    HomethreeAboutComponent,
    HomethreeMissionComponent,
    HomethreeFunfactsComponent,
    HomethreeCoursesComponent,
    HomethreeExploreLearningComponent,
    HomethreeBootcampsComponent,
    HomethreeTestimonialsComponent,
    HomethreeBlogComponent,
    SubscribeComponent,
    HomepageFourComponent,
    HomefourBlogComponent,
    HomefourTestimonialsComponent,
    HomefourIndustriesServeComponent,
    HomefourServicesComponent,
    HomefourFunfactsComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    HomefourWhatWeDoComponent,
    HomefourWhyChooseUsComponent,
    HomefourFeaturedServicesComponent,
    HomefourBannerComponent,
    AboutPageComponent,
    AboutpageAboutComponent,
    AboutpageHistoryComponent,
    TeamPageComponent,
    ServicesPageComponent,
    ServicesDetailsPageComponent,
    ContactPageComponent,
    BlogPageComponent,
    BlogDetailsPageComponent,
    RelatedServicesComponent,
    CaseStudiesDetailsPageComponent,
    RelatedCaseStudiesComponent,
    FaqPageComponent,
    EventsDetailsPageComponent,
    EventsSpeakersComponent,
    CoursesPageComponent,
    CoursesDetailsPageComponent,
    RelatedCoursesComponent,
    MLComponent,
    BigDataComponent,
    IOTComponent,
    WebComponent,
    AppsComponent,
    DataScienceComponent,
    CloudComponent,
    TrainingComponent,
    ComingSoonPageComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

AND THIS IS INDEX.HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="zxx">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Excain- Build, Train and Innovate</title>
        <base href="/">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <app-root></app-root>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Thanks in advance**

NAVBAR CODE:-

```
<li class="nav-item"><a [routerLink]="['/about-us']" class="nav-link" href = "#" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">About Us</a></li>

                        <li class="nav-item"><a [routerLink]="['/services']" class="nav-link" href = "#" routerLinkActive="active"[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">Services</a></li>

                        <li class="nav-item"><a [routerLink]="['/case-studies']" class="nav-link" href = "#" routerLinkActive="active"[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">Case Studies</a></li>

                        <li class="nav-item"><a [routerLink]="['/courses']" class="nav-link" href = "#" routerLinkActive="active"[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">Courses</a></li>

                        <li class="nav-item"><a [routerLink]="['/blog']" class="nav-link" href = "#" routerLinkActive="active"[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">Blog</a></li>
```

Comment: Try removing forward slash in `redirectTo: '/home'` -> `redirectTo: 'home'`

Comment: Have you tried checking it in your desktop?

Comment: In desktop view routes are completely fine. But when resize my window with the console, this error arises.

Comment: I suggest you try in firefox too, so we can be sure that chrome is not causing the issue.

Comment: I checked on firefox, edge, chrome explorer.

Answer (score -1):

The routing in Angular 2+ depends on the order of your routes.

Your first route with path: '' matches each request and is going to be executed.

It's recommended to sort the routes from more specific to less specific like this:

```
{path: 'home', component: HomepageFourComponent},
{path: 'about-us', component: AboutPageComponent},
{path: 'services', component: ServicesPageComponent},
{path: 'services/:id', component: ServicesDetailsPageComponent},    
{path: 'courses', component: CoursesPageComponent},
{path: 'courses/:id', component: CoursesDetailsPageComponent},    
{path: 'case-studies', component: CaseStudiesThreeColumnsPageComponent},
{path: 'case-studies/:id', component: CaseStudiesDetailsPageComponent},
{path: 'error', component: ErrorPageComponent},   
{path: 'blog', component: BlogPageComponent},  
{path: 'contact', component: ContactPageComponent},
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
{path: '**', component: ErrorPageComponent}
```

With this configuration a request to localhost:4000/ would be catched from the last route and redirect to /home. With the route '**' you would catch every request and redirect it to Error page.So it should be at last.

Also check your base is set to "base href='/'" . The documentation of Angular says that it must be "base href='/'".

Comment: I used whatever you had said but still, I am facing the same issue

Comment: And Yes this Problem occurs only to the production file and not in the development server.

Comment: Can you please share the html view where you have router-outlet and routerLink? Do you have project files resides in some folder? If yes then base href="/somefolder/".

Comment: do you want the app.component.html or the navbar HTML page

Comment: Html where you have router-outlet. I guess navbar.

Comment: Is there any different setting that we have to do for the angular app so that it can work on mobile view and I also added the navbar code.

Comment: may be you added some logic somewhere to edit index.html on mobo size

Comment: @VikasGarg `Your first route with path: '' matches each request and is going to be executed.` -> it's wrong. if you put `{ path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },` as first route, angular will not catch it and it looks for next routes. (because of `pathMatch: 'full'`)

Comment: @yaya I put path: ' ' at second last i.e. Just before wild char routes. Read before commenting. Same thing I mentioned in my comment that  Chitransh was doing. Read routing from "https://angular.io/guide/router".

Comment: @VikasGarg sorry but it seems you didn't get what i mean. here is your quote: `Your first route with path: '' matches each request and is going to be executed.`. and i said it's a wrong statement, because it has `pathMatch: 'full'` . so i think your answer is wrong. (it's ok to put that as first route.). aren't you agree?